# Can't Compare Images Received From Photo Gallery in Swift

Tags: swift

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        imgProfileIcon.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        print(info)
        if let _ = imagePicked
        {
          if imagePicked.isEqualToData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)!)
          {
            print("U Picked The Same Image")
          }
          else
          {
           print("Different Image Picked")
          }
        }
        imagePicked=UIImagePNGRepresentation(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
        isImagePicked=true
    }
```

This is the delegate function that I use to select an image from The photoLibrary and my objective is to ensure that I don't hit a web service if an user selects the same image..... So while I was trying to compare images it always prints "Different Image Picked" Even though I pick the same image from the photo library.

I've tried all possibilities....even with `.equal()` but it shows the same... I think that some additional data is added due to which the comparison fails.

Can someone help me out?